# Limit $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{3n^2-n+1}{2n^2+n+1}\right)^{\large \frac{n^2}{1-n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> I'm required to compute the limit of the following sequence:
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{3n^2-n+1}{2n^2+n+1}\right)^{\large \frac{n^2}{1-n}}$$

I'm not sure as to how to approach it. I've tried tackling it in a few ways, but none of them led me to a form I know how to tackle.

Let $a_n$ denote the base.

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{\frac{n^2}{1-n}}= \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{\large \frac{1}{1-n}}\right)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sqrt[1-n]{a_n}\right)^{n^2}=1^{\infty} $$

From there though I don't know how to compute: 
$$e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sqrt[n-1]{a_n}n^2\right)}$$

I tried using the ln function though I couldn't get any further. I'd be glad for help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\left(\frac{3n^2-n+1}{2n^2+n+1}\right)^{\frac{n^2}{1-n}}\sim c\cdot \left(\frac32\right)^{-n}$$

indeed

$$\left(\frac{3n^2-n+1}{2n^2+n+1}\right)^{\frac{n^2}{1-n}}=\left(\frac32\right)^{-n}\left(\frac{2n^2-\frac23n+\frac23}{2n^2+n+1}\right)^{\frac{n^2}{1-n}}$$

and

$$\left(\frac{2n^2-\frac23n+\frac23}{2n^2+n+1}\right)^{\frac{n^2}{1-n}}=\left[\left(1-\frac{\frac53n+\frac13}{2n^2+n+1}\right)^{\frac{2n^2+n+1}{\frac53n+\frac13}}\right]^{\frac{\frac53n^3+\frac13n^2}{(2n^2+n+1)(1-n)}}\to\left(\frac1e\right)^{-\frac56}$$

Comment: I observed that, it leads to 0 but subtituing larger values in the original form gives me other value

Comment: @Moshe To prove that we can proceed as follows $$\left(\frac{3n^2-n+1}{2n^2+n+1}\right)^{\frac{n^2}{1-n}}=\left(\frac{3n^2}{2n^2}\right)^{-\frac{n^2}{n-1}}\cdot \left(\frac{1-1/3n+1/3n^2}{1+1/2n+1/2n^2}\right)^{-\frac{n^2}{n-1}}$$ and the second part on the RHS tends to 1.

Comment: Nice and simple (as usual !). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks Claude! Much appreciative from you! Many cheers :)

Comment: "[T]he second part on the RHS" does not converge to 1 (hence the equivalence sign in the answer is wrong).

Comment: @Did Yes of course you are right! I was  too much fast in the evaluation of thet part. The result shouldn't change. I fix that suddenly. Thanks

Comment: @Moshe As noticed by Did the constant is not equal to one but it should be $\left(\frac1e\right)^{-\frac56}$. Anyway the main part doesn't change too much in the sense that the term $\left(\frac32\right)^{-n}$ leads the behaviour for the limit.

Answer (score 7):

You can estimate:
$$\frac{2n^2+n+1}{3n^2-n+1}<\frac{3}{4}, n>7;$$

$$0<\left(\frac{3n^2-n+1}{2n^2+n+1}\right)^{\large \frac{n^2}{1-n}}=\left(\frac{2n^2+n+1}{3n^2-n+1}\right)^{\large \frac{n^2}{n-1}}<\left(\frac34\right)^{\large \frac{n^2}{n-1}}=\left(\frac34\right)^{n+1+\large \frac{1}{n-1}}\to 0.$$

Comment: very nice alternative approach (+1).

Comment: Thank you gimusi.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reduce this to the limit form of the exponential function, because the limit of the *content of* the bracket is 3/2. But the exponent becomes more as $-n$ as $n\to\infty$; so you have the the reciprocal of a positive-exponentially increasing number.